# How to restore user defined javascript functions in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I restored MongoDB production database to our testing environment using the mongodump and mongorestore commands. There were 414 user defined functions in our database and none of them were restored. How can I restore the functions in the production environment in the testing environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is pretty simple. The system.js function is also a collection. So you can dump the collection using the following command and restore using the mongorestore command.

```
mongodump --host youripaddressorlocal --port yourportnumber --username "username" --password "password" --authenticationDatabase admin --collection system.js --db databasename

mongorestore --host localhost  --port 27017  --username "username" --password "yourpassword"  --collection system.js --drop --db yourdatabase dump/baabtra_db/system.js.bson
```

--drop is used so that if the function is already there, it will be deleted. Incase if you are still getting the error and if you are not able to delete it, you can use the following command to delete all the functions in the mongoDb.

```
db.system.js.remove({})
```

Please note that the curly braces are very important.